# How to change a control's Placeholder by device?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Using Sitecore 7 - Is there a way I can specify what the placeholder of a template's control will be based on device?

Example : `Placeholder A if the device is Mobile else Placeholder B`

This is more to do with positioning the content differently in Mobile than desktop site.

**UPDATE**

Trayek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18866821/976117) is great and would sure work. Although, I ended up using a different approach.

In the layout details of my template, I added a control C; set its placeholder as A and added *HideBydevice* ***Desktop*** in the additional Parameters section. Then, I again added control C; set its placeholder as B and added *HideBydevice* ***Mobile*** in the additional Parameters section.

Then in my code, I check *HideBydevice* parameter's value and hide the sublayout/control, if the parameter's value is the same as **Sitecore.Context.Device.Name**

This worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can probably do is use Sitecore's [Rules Engine](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/06/All-About-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Rules-Engine.aspx), where you can create (or use a pre-existing) `Condition` to find out whether you are on a mobile device (to do this, you could use the [Mobile Device Detector](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Mobile_Device_Detector.aspx) for instance - although I don't know if that module is supported on Sitecore 7). 

Then, you can also use the `Action` `Set placeholder to value`.

You could also create your own Action instead, of course. All you'd have to do is get the `RenderingReference` and simply change the placeholder like so:

```
var reference = new RenderingReference(this.RenderingID);
reference.Placeholder = "A";
```

More on this in the [Rules Engine Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/61/rules_engine_cookbook_sc61_a4.pdf)

**Update**
I've written a blog post about how to get this done: [Read it here](http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/changing-placeholders-with-rules/).

Comment: Thanks, Trayek. That was exactly what I was looking at. I created a conditional rendering Global Rule. Now, apparently I can configure conditional rendering in layout details of standard values for the data template. But, the only option I see is to personalize the relevant control. And there is no option to insert a rule in the Personalization section. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you've added it to '/sitecore/system/settings/rules/conditional renderings/global rules' that rule will automatically run for each component. Your Conditional Rendering Rule item you created has a Rule field, which you can use. Just click Edit Rule, select one (or more) condition(s) and one (or more) action(s). I.e. 'where the device is mobile' (default rule from the Mobile Device Detector module) with the action 'set placeholder to B'. You might want to include a custom conditino to detect which placeholder it's targetting to begin with, otherwise all will end up there :-)

Comment: Somya, if this answer was or led you to the solution to your question then you should accept it, as it might help others in the community, as well. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to my blog, which will give an example of how to do it exactly.

Comment: Yes, Zachary. I was just waiting to implement this and get it working, before I mark it as answer :)

Comment: Thanks, Trayek for a great blog post :) I actually ended up using a different approach to solve this - but that is, of course, before I read your blog post. I have updated my question with the approach I took. Marked your solution as answer anyway. Thanks again!