# Sitecore: know the placeholder the current sublayout is in?

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to know which placeholder a sublayout is sitting in through code?

Scenario: I would like for a sublayout to appear a little different if it is in Placeholder B as opposed to Placeholder A. I could do this with sublayout parameters but I am trying to make it so an author doesn't have to set up a value and rather the sublayout is just smart enough to know what context it is being used in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably do something clever with the Rules Engine, and this is probably how I would tackle this - possible change a rendering parameter using the Rules Engine based on the Placeholder and then do something in your code based on that...

But you can doing the following from code:

```cs
Sublayout sublayout = this.Parent as Sublayout;
if (sublayout != null)
{
    Placeholder placeholder = sublayout.Parent as Placeholder;
    if (placeholder != null)
    {
        // name of the container placeholder
        string placeHolderKey = placeholder.Key;
        // full path of nested placeholders
        string placeHolderContextKey = placeholder.ContextKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @jammykam says I would also encourage you to use Rules Engine to achieve a solution.
And for that I will point you in the direction of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866001/how-to-change-a-controls-placeholder-by-device?answertab=active#tab-top) on Stackoverflow for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866001/how-to-change-a-controls-placeholder-by-device)(I think)

This should give you a good insight into the similar sort of scenario which the other user was facing.

Finally would encourage you to read [Trayek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064919/trayek)'s [blog](http://trayek.wordpress.com/) post on [Changing placeholders with Rules](http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/changing-placeholders-with-rules/)

Hope the above helps and get you the solution that you are after.